# Outlook 2010 - double click calendar to make meeting requests, not appointments?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010

In the Outlook 2010 calendar, if you double click a timeslot you will create an appointment by default. Is there a way to create a meeting request by default instead?

(Meeting requests have attendees, appointments don't)

Answer (score 10):

Its late but might help others who are searching for the same. You can still use double click on the time slot and by default you will get appointment request. Then you should be able to click on the "Invite" button in the appointment tab to convert it to a meeting request. If you don't see Invite button then try maximizing the buttons bar (in the mac, its at the right hand corner of the appointment tab. See http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/outlook/item/79c17be2-28ff-4f0f-a691-2dfbe559e133

Comment: Does not save any clicks either.

Answer (score 6):

While this doesn't answer the need of double-clicking for a Meeting Request by default, I've found a keyboard shortcut alternative will create a meeting request directly from Calendar view.

Perform these steps in Calendar view:

1. Select the time block(s) required for your Meeting.  They should be highlighted in blue (assuming default color scheme).
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

A new Meeting Request window will appear with the "To..." line and all relevant menu items already visible.  Your cursor will be active in the "To..." line for immediate entry of attendees.

This eliminates the extra mouse clicks/movements inherent in the previously proposed responses.

Comment: This is good to know for future reference.

In this case, however, I believe that the relevant information was conveyed in the post; I only provided the source for greater context for anyone interested in further reading.

Edit: If this is not a standard or is generally frowned upon, I'll be happy to delete the link.  Advice would be genuinely appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Please check out the help center to understand our expectations out of answers.  I see a great deal of information in that link that should be in your answer.

Comment: Thanks again for the recommendation.  I've refactored the response to better detail the steps necessary to perform an action equivalent to the asker's need.  Upon review of the link, I recognized that the information therein is actually related to actions performed after creation of a meeting request.  I've removed it on grounds of irrelevance.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of double-clicking **on a time slot, right-click** on it and **select meeting request** from the popup menu. After a little while, this will become second nature for you.

Comment: Personally, I don't this is a helpful alternative as the user expressed the desire to double click to quickly create the meeting.  Shital's answer was a much better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the default to open a meeting instead of an appointment, but you do not have to do anything to get it to change to a meeting besides adding attendees like you would if it had opened as a meeting.

You don't have to specifically click the add invitees button, you can add attendees in any of the half dozen methods available and it will automatically change to a meeting once the first person is added.

Also for those who may be looking for the opposite: if you are double clicking and getting a meeting and you want an appointment (it is because it is a shared calendar) and all you have to do to change it to an appointment is click the  VERY INTUITIVE "Cancel Invitation" button. Now it is an appointment.
[Picture of the Cancel Invitation button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suYzA.png)